# grep some archived logs using find and xargs

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a list of IP's in a csv file and I need to search for any encounters of this IP's in a whole bunch of archived logs but only for file in January.

I first tried this:

```
for i in `cat /tmp/ips.csv`; do zgrep -rHc $i /webstats/2010/some_dir/*/*.2010-01*.access.gz ; done
```

But that doesn't work. I get:

```
bash: /usr/bin/zgrep: Argument list too long
```

However I thought using find + xargs but I'm not that sure on how I should build my expression.
I was thinking of this:

```
find /logs/2010/some_dir/ -name *.2010-01*.access.gz -type f -print0 | xargs zgrep -rHc `/tmp/ips.csv` {}
```

But something doesn't look that good.

Comment: cat file | grep IP | grep DATE ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
find /logs/2010/some_dir -name '*.2010-01*.access.gz' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -Hc -f /tmp/ips.csv
```